# Método splice() en JavaScript necesita de una variable para mostrar valores eliminados

Tags: javascript, método

El siguiente código contiene un array con varias ciudades polacas. Quiero eliminar algunas de ellas y añadir otras ciudades bielorrusas mediante el método `splice()`. Pretendo mostrar en pantalla tres párrafos, uno con el array original, otro con el array resultante y el último con las ciudades eliminadas.

```js
const cities = ["Warszawa", "Kraków", "Wrocław ", "Gdańsk"];
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Polish cities:<br> " + cities;
//let deleted = cities.splice(2, 2, "Pinsk", "Minsk"); 
cities.splice(2, 2, "Pinsk", "Minsk"); 
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "Polish & Belorussian cities:<br>" + cities;
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Deleted Polish cities:<br> " + cities.splice(); 
//document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = "Deleted Polish cities:<br> " + deleted;
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <h2>Mixing Polish and Belorussian cities with splice() method</h2>

    
    <p id="demo1"></p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    <p id="demo3"></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

El código JavaScript contiene dos líneas comentadas que solucionan el problema: primero asignando el método a una variable y luego mostrándola en pantalla. También habría que comentar o eliminar las líneas 4 y 6 del script.

Me surgen dos preguntas:

1. ¿Por qué el código `cities.splice()` no muestra los dos valores eliminados si no es mediante una variable?
2. ¿El método **.splice()** no debería funcionar, en este caso, igual que el método **.shift()**, mostrando los elementos eliminados por sí solo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Son dos funciones totalmente diferentes, ¿porqué deberían comportarse igual? Por otro lado, si no asignas el resultado de cualquiera de esas dos funciones a una variable, el mismo se pierde. ¿Cuál es el problema o duda? ¿Has revisado la documentación de ambos métodos?. Esto: `cities.splice()`, devuelve un `Array` vacío, ya que para que `splice` funcione debes indicarle,mediante ciertos argumentos, los elementos que deseas eliminar de la lista. Por otro lado, `shift` elimina el elemento del índice 0 de la lista, sin necesidad de argumentos. Saludos